# Unwanted space below vertical stack using interface builder

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints, interface-builder

There is an unwanted space below my last container ("Container View 5") that I can't seem to get rid of. All 5 of my container views are within a vertical stack view. The bottom space of the stack view is set to the superview and should have no space. Any idea what I am missing?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the constraints / layout in your **actual** `iPad View With Table Bottom Detail` ... there is nothing wrong with your constraints (unless there's something else you haven't shown). Stack view Distribution should be `Fill`.

Comment: I just now saw your comment.. thanks a ton that is what I found out to be the problem.. the separate view that was embedded in the container was the issue! It was not properly filled to the view and instead the safe area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not the stack or containers but the constraints on a separate view itself that I embedded in the last container. The constraints on the containers and stack work great.

Answer (score 0):

You have force-dictated the heights of the Container Views 2-5, so there is no reason why they would, taken together, fill the height of the device.

To see this, simply imagine that Container View 1 has a height of 10. Then the other views have a combined height of 67.5, for a grand total of 77.5, which obviously would be smaller than the height of *any* known device.

Basically this appears to be an incorrect use of a stack view. You don't give any information about how the stack view is configured, so it's impossible to say more at this point. I'm a little surprised, though, that you do not report getting some sort of constraint conflict message in the Xcode console.

Comment: Thanks! I am using proportional heights within the stack view so I was thinking everything within would follow proportions and the overall constraints of the stack... maybe I don't understand how proportional heights work? Is there a better way to do this?